# Tracer active and startActive deprecated

Tags: java, opentracing

With active and startActive being deprecated, what are the "proper" method of doing

```
tracer
    .buildSpan(instructions)
    .startActive()
    .span()
    .setTag("id", id);
```

and then, if need be, stop scope with

```
tracer
    .scopeManager()
    .active()
    .close();
```

Ive tried replacing active with activeSpan as per deprecation notes but cant really get the scope from the span?

did some googling buut didnt really find much info on this